# What is the difference between AppTy and FunTy in Haskell Core type definitions?

Tags: haskell

Reading [Core Haskell Type](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/type-type), and would really appreciate if someone could explain the difference between `FunTy` and `AppTy` with examples. Don't know what the norms are, but including the relevant portion from the page (let me know if this is discouraged):

```
type TyVar = Var

data Type = TyVarTy TyVar       -- Type variable
      | AppTy Type Type         -- Application
      | TyConApp TyCon [Type]   -- Type constructor application
      | FunTy Type Type         -- Arrow type
      | ForAllTy Var Type       -- Polymorphic type
      | LitTy TyLit             -- Type literals

data TyLit = NumTyLit Integer           -- A number
           | StrTyLit FastString        -- A string
```

Comment: `FunTy` constructs a function type, so `a -> b`, whereas`AppTy` you perform an application, so `(a b)` where `a` is for example `Maybe` and `b` is an `Int`, then `AppTy` will produce `Maybe Int`.

Comment: That means I don't understand something else also in the definition :(. What is the purpose of `TyConApp`? In my head I was using your example above using `TyConApp`.

Comment: `TyConApp` is for applications of type constructors. `AppTy` is for other applications, e.g. variable applied to variable like `f a` or type synonym like `X a` where `type X = ...`. As per the linked page: "if the head of a type application is a TyCon, GHC always uses the TyConApp constructor, not AppTy. This invariant is maintained internally by 'smart constructors'."

Comment: Actually maybe just type variable applications, since it seems that `Type` is specifically used to represent normalized types, where type synonym applications may not occur.

Comment: @stan_plogic Perhaps part of your confusion is a common misconception: "type constructor" does not mean "type with an arrow in its kind". Rather, it means a thing declared by `data` or `newtype`, i.e., something starting with an upper case letter. Examples: `Maybe` (constructor, arrow kind); `Bool` (constructor, no arrow in kind); `Either Int` (not constructor, arrow kind); `Either Int Bool` (not constructor, no arrow in kind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Type` is an AST for a core type-level expression, like `Int`, or `Maybe Int`, or `a -> Maybe (a,b)` or whatever.

All of `AppTy`, `TyConApp`, and `FunTy` represent the application of one type-level expression to another type-level expression.

The most general is `AppTy Type Type`, which represents the application of any `Type` (i.e., type-level expression) to any other `Type` (i.e., type-level expression).

A `FunTy Type Type` is a special case of type application, representing the application of a specific constructor, namely the `(->)` constructor to its two `Type` arguments.  The type-level expression `FunTy x y` is semantically equivalent to `AppTy (AppTy arrowType x) y` where `arrowType` is some `Type` representing the function type constructor `(->)`.  (In the actual GHC code, the `FunTy` constructor is more complicated than the simplified version presented in the Wiki, but you can ignore that for now.)

A `TyConApp` is another special case, representing the application of any constructor (type `TyCon`) to zero or more arguments.  A `TyConApp` need not be saturated, so the following `Type`s are semantically equivalent:

```
TyConApp pairTyCon [x, y]
AppTy (TyConApp pairTyCon [x]) y
AppTy (AppTy (TyConApp pairTyCon []) x) y
```

In particular, if `maybeTyCon :: TyCon`, `pairTyCon :: TyCon`, and `arrowTyCon :: TyCon` represent the type constructors for `Maybe`, `(,)`, and `(->)` respectively, and `aVar, bVar :: Var` represent the type variables `a` and `b` respectively then the type expression `a -> Maybe (a,b)` would most likely be represented as:

```
FunTy (TyVarTy aVar) (TyConApp maybeTyCon [TyVarTy aVar, TyVarTy bVar])
```

but could also be represented as:

```
AppTy (TyConApp arrowTyCon [TyVarTy aVar])
      (TyConApp Maybe [AppTy (AppTy (TyConApp pairTyCon []) (TyVarTy aVar)) (TyVarTy bVar)])
```

Which way a given application is represented and how long it gets represented that way depends on how it was formed and various internal compiler rules/invariants.  It may be helpful to look at the actual compiler source (`.../GHC/Core/TyCo/Rep.hs`).  For example, a comment in the source indicates that `AppTy`'s first field isn't allowed to be a `TyConApp`, which disallows most of the "equivalent" representations I've described above, though they are disallowed by internal compiler rules/invariants, not by the `Type` representation itself.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by 'saturated' here:
```
... TyConApp need not be saturated...
```

Comment: "Saturated" means that something's been supplied with all its arguments.  So, a two-argument type constructor like `(,)` is saturated if it's been applied to two types:  `(,) Int Int == (Int, Int)`.  So, all I mean above is that `TyConApp constuctor arglist` can have a arglist with fewer arguments than its constructor takes (e.g., `TyConApp pairTyCon []` supplies zero arguments to its two-argument `pairTyCon` constructor and remains unsaturated).